# Equal height in table columns

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am working on a team member page and so far I have managed to get the team members info and their title columns to be the same height using tables.

Now, I am trying to get each team member sections to be the same height too but I am having real trouble.

The basic html is:

```
<div class="team-item-wrapper">

        <div class="team-item">

           <div class="left-column">

                <div class="team-image"></div>

                <div class="team-excerpt"><?php the_content(); ?>
                </div>

            </div><!--/ Left Column -->

            <div class="right-column">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h2 class="team-title"></h2>
                    <div class="divider"</div>
                    <div class="team-position"></div>
                </div><!--/ Inner -->
            </div><!--/ Right Column -->

        </div><!--/ Team Item -->

    </div><!--/ Team Item Wrapper -->
```

The CSS is:

```
.team-item-wrapper{
    padding: 0px 40px 20px 0px;
    display: table;
    width:50%;
    float:left;}

.team-item .left-column{
    width:65%;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-right:20px;}

.team-item .right-column{
    width:35%;
    display: table-cell;
    position:relative;}

.team-item .right-column .inner{
    text-align:right;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;}
```

I have tried a few CSS methods but these didn't seem to affect the table cells at all. I have also tried this JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var maxHeight = 0;
        $(".level").each(function(){
        maxHeight = $(this).height() > maxHeight ? $(this).height() : maxHeight;
        }).height(maxHeight);
</script>
```

Would anyone suggest a method to make all columns equal height?

### Update

Yes, the right and left column are equal. I mentioned I had already achieved this using tables. What I am trying to do is "team-items" the same height.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you want. left-column and right-column ARE of the same height: https://jsfiddle.net/kqehyz2h/1/ table-cell works exactly like a <td>, table-row like <tr> and "table" as <table>. Just use that one on one with the table you had, and it should work.

Comment: @RachelGallen - the question asks for equal height in **table** columns, the css sets divs to `display:table-cell`, I did not go to the link provided as I'm not stupid enough to follow blind links on SO. I thought the question was about tabular data (the word table kinda suggests that) - yes, tables are a stupid (90's) way to achieve page layouts - but a perfect way to display tabular data - my mistake for daring to suggest using tables

Comment: you could set a min-height and overflow-y to scroll or auto?

Comment: @RachelGallen Why are tables a really bad idea for displaying info in a columnar fashion?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the $(document).ready function.

```
var maxHeight = function(){
  var m = 0;
  $('.team-item-wrapper').each(function(){
    if($(this).outerHeight() > m){
       m = $(this).outerHeight();
    } 
 });
 return m;
}

$('.team-item .left-column, .team-item .right-column').height(maxHeight())
```

Then add

```
vertical-align:center
```

to the .left-column and .right-column classes.
This will set all team items to the height of team item that has the highest height.

Comment: This is great and does seem to work. Only problem is there now seems to be a massive spacing at the top of the team photo.

Comment: Have you add the style to to the left-column and right-column classes?